# Different height items in a WPF listbox

Tags: wpf, listbox

I'm wondering when modelling a real-world scenario such as a shelf stacking if it's possible to have different height items in a list box.

Assume the list box is meant to represent a shelf which is which has a height in inches or cm. I can stack boxes on this shelf up to the maximum height. I can have more smaller boxes and obviously less larger boxes. I know the dimensions of these boxes as well in inches or cm.

I'd imagine that I'll need to maintain a running total of all the items in the list box so as to know just how much shelf space I have left. I need to be able to visually show that one box is larger than the other by spanning n number of items.

Is the list box even the right control to consider using in this instance?

Comment: Yes its the right control. Yes you can have different heights of items in a ListBox. Use DataTemplates to define the style of each container which ListBox will use to represent items. Each item will become a container with its individual height and style.

Comment: Enough to get me started. Please propose as an answer and I will accept ;-)

Comment: If you don't need the selection capabilities of a `ListBox`, I'd actually recommend switching to an `ItemsControl`. It allows for a much more flexible design, and I think it's more lightweight than a `ListBox`

Comment: Thanks @Rachel - appreciate. I have behaviours and so on written for drag and drop so at this stage I'll stick with the ListBox. BTW some really good WPF articles on your site! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, its the right control. Yes you can have different heights of items in a ListBox. Use DataTemplates to define the style of each container which ListBox will use to represent items. Each item will become a container with its individual height and style.

Take a look at those link:

http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/

http://wpftutorial.net/ListBoxDataTemplate.html